# Analysis of the full bridge bidirectional converter's buck mode operation?

Tags: duty-cycle, buck-boost

[This](http://file.scirp.org/Html/1-6201318_19013.htm#txtF2) is the circuit I was trying to learn.

Here is the equivalent of the buck mode operation:
[image]

And following is the waveform in the buck mode of operation:
[image]

My intention is to derive the output voltage equation.
Theory used, Voltage across an inductor, averaged over a steady state cycle time, must always be zero

Mode - 1    (When MOSFET is ON)

V<sub>L1</sub> = Vin * (1/n) - V<sub>CLV</sub>            for   0≤t≤DT       ------- (1)

D = Duty Cycle
T = Time Period

There is a dip in the output inductor waveform, hope it is the dead time to avoid the cross conduction.

Now I need to evaluate the second part of the inductor voltage equation when MOSFET is OFF. After solving both the equations using the theory I have mentioned, can evaluate output voltage equation. But I am  stuck with the second part of equation.

**Edit**

Let me make an effort to do mode-2 (MOSFET is OFF) inductor voltage analysis

V<sub>L2</sub> = Vin - V<sub>CLV</sub>   for DT ≤ t ≤T

Since net voltage over a steady state cycle is zero,

( V<sub>L1</sub> + V<sub>L2</sub> ) / 2 = Zero,

From this, V<sub>CLV</sub> = V<sub>OUT</sub> = V<sub>in</sub> * ((D/n) -D + 1 )

Please recheck and confirm the derivation

Comment: All the state equations are given in your link.

Comment: I have made an effort to derive the output equation, but not fully convinced with it